# Show/Hide Barcolor from Input Settings

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

how to make checkbox option to Show/Hide in Input Settings (so we don't need go to input style tab to show/hide it) for bar coloring with conditional below?

```
//Conditions
L_adx = DIPlus > DIMinus and ADX > th
S_adx = DIPlus < DIMinus and ADX > th

BAR_COLOR_ADX = L_adx ? color.lime : S_adx ? color.red :  color.orange

barcolor(title="ADX Bar Color", color = BAR_COLOR_ADX)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `input.bool()` function to get the user input in a checkbox form. Then use this input as a condition for your color variable. Set it to `na` if it is unchecked.

```
show_barcolor = input.bool(defval=true, title="Show barcolor?")

BAR_COLOR_ADX = show_barcolor ? L_adx ? color.lime : S_adx ? color.red :  color.orange : na
barcolor(title="ADX Bar Color", color = BAR_COLOR_ADX)
```